# Docker Windows to windows volume on network drive

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I have a Macbook and am developing a .Net application (it's *not* .net core and a transition to .net core is not in the near-term plans). I therefore run a Windows Pro environment via Parallels which I use to map my Macbook home `~` directory to the in-parallels `Y:` drive. I store all my code on my Macbook which makes it easier to code for example via emacs.

```
PS Y:\foo> Get-PSDrive

Name           Used (GB)     Free (GB) Provider      Root                                                                                
----           ---------     --------- --------      ----                                                                                
...
Y                 155.34        775.38 FileSystem    \\Mac\Home
```

For a variety of reasons I am currently trying to dockerize my application in a way that I can develop directly against the docker container (ie I cannot `ADD` code, I have to create a `VOLUME` because I don't want to reboot the container every time I change a js file).

Frustratingly, I cannot seem to create a volume for my `Y:` drive. I created a very simple application `foo` where I'm trying to map `foo/content` to the in-container `/site` directory.

This works:

```
PS Y:\foo> docker run --name iis -p 8000:8000 -v c:/foo/content:c:/site iis-test
```

This fails:

```
PS Y:\foo> docker run --name iis -p 8000:8000 -v y:/foo/content:c:/site iis-test
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: invalid bind mount spec "y:/foo/content:c:/site": invalid volume specification: 'y:/foo/content:c:/site': invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist.
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe run --help'.
```

Is this a limitation of Docker that I cannot use a mapped network drive? Is this a limitation of Docker for Windows Beta? Is there anything else that I can try?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can find, it seems to be a limitation within "Windows and the base image" that MS is tracking internally and cannot be fixed by Docker for Windows.

[More info here](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/124)